# Two simultaneous long polls and long polling disables ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling

The first long poll works fine, but the second one doesn't work. Also, any ajax requests are not working unless I abort the first long poll

Is this normal for long polling?

These are the ajax requests.

```js
function CheckExpired() {
    console.log("Checking Expiry");
    CheckExpirationVar = $.ajax({
        url: 'CheckExpiry.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            // Logs data and reloop
            console.log(data);
            CheckExpired();
        }
    });
}

function CheckDB(TradeID) {
    CheckDBVar = $.ajax({ url: 'CheckDB.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            ID: TradeID
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            lastID = obj.id
            
            // Logs data and returns to loop
            CheckDB(lastID);
        }
    });
}
```

These are the php codes:

This first one is for the CheckDB ajax.

```php
<?php session_start();
    // set php runtime to unlimited
    set_time_limit(0);
    
    include "../php/ConnToDB.php";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE EntryTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 20 SECOND ORDER BY ID DESC";
    while(true) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($tradeRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                
                if ($_POST["ID"] == $tradeRow["ID"]) {
                    sleep(1);
                    continue;
                }
                
                // Check if one of the trades of the user is the same
                $tradeSql = "SELECT * FROM UserTransactions WHERE UserID = {$_SESSION['UserID']}";
                $tradeResult = mysqli_query($conn, $tradeSql);
                
                if (mysqli_num_rows($tradeResult) > 2) {
                    sleep(1);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    while ($temp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tradeResult)) {
                        $trades[$temp["TradeID"]] = 123;
                    }
                }
                
                // START THE CHECKING OF THE NEW TRADE
                if (!isset($trades[$tradeRow["ID"]]) && isset($_SESSION["Traders"][$tradeRow["MasterID"]])) {
                    
                    $Investment = $_SESSION["Traders"][$tradeRow["MasterID"]]["Investment"];
                    
                    $_SESSION["CurrentTrade"] = array(
                        "ID" => $tradeRow["ID"],
                        "TraderID" => $tradeRow["MasterID"]
                    );
                    
                    $returnArr = array(
                        "id" => $tradeRow["ID"],
                        "direction" => $tradeRow["Direction"],
                        "expiration" => $tradeRow["Expiration"],
                        "assetID" => $tradeRow["Asset_ID"],
                        "Investment" => $Investment,
                        "TraderID" => $tradeRow["MasterID"]
                    );
                    
                    echo json_encode($returnArr);
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is for the check expiry ajax call.

```php
<?php session_start();
    // set php runtime to unlimited
    set_time_limit(0);
    
    include "../php/ConnToDB.php";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM UserTransactions WHERE UserID = {$_SESSION["UserID"]} AND ExpirationDate <= NOW()";
    while(true) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $deleteSql = "DELETE FROM UserTransactions WHERE TradeID = {$row['TradeID']}";
                mysqli_query($conn, $deleteSql);
                
                $return = array(
                    "TransactionID" => $row["TransactionID"],
                    "TraderID" => $row["TraderID"]
                );
                
                echo json_encode($return);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: really depends on your code - javascript is "single threaded" (for want of a better term) - so if you have a loop running, nothing else can execute until that loop ends

Comment: @JaromandaX How about requesting an ajax and setting a settimeout and rerun? Will it be running fine?

Comment: erm ... yes? now? maybe? did you try? words aren't as good as sample code

Comment: Can we see this mysterious code?

Comment: I just uploaded it

Comment: Making constant requests like that is going to overload server like a denial of service attack would. Consider using websockets instead

Comment: I can't use websockets because I use a shared hosting